# how to call javascript of facebook api for sending dynamic values in order to post in wall

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I have a parent page where I am submiting a form and calling two funcions `on_click` of the submit button. One function from the same page and another from child page.

I am wondering how to call a Javascript funcion on the parent page from the child page to post on a Facebook wall. [This](http://www.ebhasin.com/apps/apps-source/precussion/) is my application.

**My parent.php:**

```
<form action="child.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" value="$result" name="codebox">
   <input type="submit" onclick="funcion codeload();function postToFeed();"/>
</form>
```

**My child.php:**

```
 <body> 
  <?PHP
          $son=$_REQUEST['codebox'];
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['sony'] =$son;
          $ashutosh=$_SESSION['sony'] ;
          $tinyurl = file_get_contents("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?                 
                url=http://www.ebhasin.com/approval/files/main.php?a=$ashutosh");
          $desc='Place here description what you want';
  ?>
<div id='fb-root'></div> 
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>

<p id='msg'></p>    

<script>

  FB.init({appId: "313877282043416", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
       link: '<?PHP echo $tinyurl?>',
            picture: 'http://www.dogoscanarios.com/en/themes/dogotheme/images/icon_dot_cat.gif',
      name: 'Drum Precussion',
    caption: ' I just created a new Drum Loop using Drum Beats Pro! Come listen to it!',
      description: '.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand, what your actual problem is – not at all.

Comment: Please check my question above. Now i have clearly mention my problem.

Comment: What is a “parent” and what a “child page” in your glossary? Are we talking about frame/iframes here? Otherwise talking about parent/childs does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Sorry,   Parent page is one php page and child page is another php page. Here i am not using any IFRAME. Just a simple php page  which calls a   Javascript function of Child.php page to open in popup for posting in facebook wall. I hope now you understand my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if lets say the parent window opens a child popup window, then do as following

**EDIT :**

**Your parent page, parent.php**

```
 <script>
var Popup;
function popUp()
{
    Popup = window.open("child.php", "bpPopup", 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=420,height=300,left = 490,top = 262');
    Popup.focus();
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="popUp();">Open child window</a><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Popup.postToFeed();">Call child window function</a>
```

First link opens popup window, second link calls the function `postToFeed()` in popup window from parent.

**Your child popup window, child.php**

```
<script>
function postToFeed(){
    alert("Popup function called by parent window");
}
</script>
```

This function in popup window is called after you click the link in parent window.

Hope This helps!

Comment: Sorry but it is not solving my problem. I want to call  a javascript function of child.php page into my parent.php page on submission of a link. eg. in our simple programs,we are calling javascript funcion in a page by just giving the location in our header section.(same  thing i am looking for my above question)

Comment: @lovesangprince, you mean you want to call child page's function from parent page??

Comment: yes exactly. i want to call postToFeed() function  on parent.php page.

Comment: @lovesangprince, without opening popup window you can't call its function from parent.

Comment: okay then, Is it possible to call both the functions in a single click. {both functions means: opening popop & calling alert function}". Because i do not want to call the postToFeed() function in two clicks"

Comment: @lovesangprince, open popup window with a link and in `child.php` page call `postToFeed` function in windows onload event like this 
`<script>window.onload=function(){ postToFeed();}</script>`

Comment: yes same things i did before but it was giving problem saying that "Enable javascript popop" in the browser to run this script.

Comment: @lovesangprince, well i tried here, it worked without any problem

Comment: for simple alert it is working fine but when i am calling that facebook function() for posting it in wall then it is saying me "to enable popop"

Comment: please  copy and paste My child.php contents in your child.php page then check you will get the same  massage  saying "enable popop"

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a PHP script that your form submits to, that posts to the Facebook feed. The reason being, it will still work if JavaScript is not available for some reason. You can then use JavaScript to submit the form via AJAX, which will have the result you want.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place to get developers to write code for you.

Comment: i am not saying you to sit and  write code for me. Just i am asking you  to share ur code. Either through any links or giving a sample of it with small logic....(This much help is required for a fresher to solve their doubt.)

Comment: @lovesang prince I haven't written any code. I've given an answer based on experience, not something I've got away and written. Break the problem down into stages, and tackle them independently, and then ask specific questions along the way if you get stuck.